# Scrapy MapCompose: How to use with w3lib remove_tags with keep=() option?

Tags: python, scrapy

The following default output processor works fine, but I want to keep the 'p' tags only.

```
l.default_output_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), replace_escape_chars, remove_tags)
```

How do I add the `keep=('p',)` option such as `remove_tags(text, keep=('p',))`? What should "text" be in the `MapCompose` statement? Or how should this be done? I can't find an example.

Comment: Can you be abit more explicit about what you're trying to achieve ? Can you not use a XPATH selector to specify p tags specifically instead of putting it through an output processor ?

Comment: I’m trying to remove all tags from the response except the p tags. How would I use an xpath selector to do that?

Comment: XPATH is pretty flexible in that it depends on the XPATH get() and getall() methods to remove tags. You've not been specific on what data you're trying to obtain, but you want to find an XPATH selector that finds the p tags of whatever you're doing. For example response.xpath('//p') would be the most general.

Comment: The text is of a variety of types, but this is an example. <div class="one"><p><span><font face="y">x<br />z</span><span>x</span></p></div><div class="one"><p><span><font face="y">x<br />z</span><span>x</span></p></div>  I can remove ALL the tags, but then I get a morass of text and have to manually go back and find paragraphs and put the p tags back in.

Comment: There is inline formatting on almost every word of the main content.

Comment: I really think you need to be abit more specific on what you're trying to achieve, why do you specifically need <p> tags on the text?  and the URL will help. Sounds like you're needing to chunk down blocks of the HTML using XPATH selectors and by using for loops to get the text you want.

Comment: There are many urls. This is one example. It uses br tags instead of p tags. I need the main summary. In this case with only the br tags intact. I need the paragraph tags intact because the content is piped directly into another website via a database. If the paragraph formatting goes away, I get one big block of text. http://www.motie.go.kr/motie/ne/presse/press2/bbs/bbsView.do?bbs_cd_n=81&cate_n=1&bbs_seq_n=163191

Comment: Use [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to define an alternative to `remove_tags` that calls `remove_tags` with that parameter, and use that alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a new function such as;

```
def remove_p_tags(value):
    return remove_tags(value, which_ones=('p',)).strip()
```

and then add that function to MapCompose()